# Using Countdown Timer on additional page

Tags: java, android, xml

Really new to Android coding & Java.

I've got a simple date countdown timer which is working fine when it's on 1 screen, what I want to do is have that same code but on a 2nd screen.

1st screen will have a onClick method that takes you to the 2nd screen that will have the date countdown.

It does work on the hone but the countdown timer is missing, it has all the back ground & text but no countdown.

The code mentioned in on the displayfloridaactivity.java (this is different from the MainActivity.Java

The code is not showing with any error's and will work on the phone, but the date countdown

```
package com.example.countdown;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import static com.example.countdown.MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE;

public class DisplayFloridaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_display_florida );
}

public void Florida(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent( this, DisplayFloridaActivity.class );
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editText );
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra( EXTRA_MESSAGE, message );
    startActivity( intent );

}

    public class DisplayFloridactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView txtDay, txtHour, txtMinute, txtSecond;
    private TextView tvEventStart;
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;
    private Bundle savedInstanceState;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

        txtDay = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.txtDay );
        txtHour = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.txtHour );
        txtMinute = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.txtMinute );
        txtSecond = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.txtSecond );
        tvEventStart = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.tveventStart );

        countDownStart();
    }

    public void countDownStart() {
        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.postDelayed( this, 1000 );
                try {
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "dd-MM-yyyy" );
                    Date futureDate = dateFormat.parse( "31-8-2020" );
                    Date currentDate = new Date();
                    if (!currentDate.after( futureDate )) {
                        long diff = futureDate.getTime()
                                - currentDate.getTime();
                        long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                        diff -= days * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                        long hours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
                        diff -= hours * (60 * 60 * 1000);
                        long minutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
                        diff -= minutes * (60 * 1000);
                        long seconds = diff / 1000;
                        txtDay.setText( "" + String.format( "%02d", days ) );
                        txtHour.setText( "" + String.format( "%02d", 
hours ) );
                        txtMinute.setText( "" + String.format( "%02d", 
minutes ) );
                        txtSecond.setText( "" + String.format( "%02d", 
seconds ) );
                    } else {
                        tvEventStart.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                        tvEventStart.setText( "Holiday is over, get a new 
one booked ASAP!" );
                        textViewGone();

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed( runnable, 1 * 1000 );
    }

    public void textViewGone() {
        findViewById( R.id.LinearLayout1 ).setVisibility( View.GONE );
        findViewById( R.id.LinearLayout2 ).setVisibility( View.GONE );
        findViewById( R.id.LinearLayout3 ).setVisibility( View.GONE );
        findViewById( R.id.LinearLayout4 ).setVisibility( View.GONE );
        findViewById( R.id.textViewheader1 ).setVisibility( View.GONE );
        findViewById( R.id.textViewheader2 ).setVisibility( View.GONE );
    }
}    }
```

no errors on code that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you start correct activity?
In your intent you specify `DisplayFloridaActivity` (upper case A in Activty) but your code is in `DisplayFloridactivity` (lower case a in activty).

Comment: Changed that, now it's thrown a duplicate class error - public class DisplayFloridaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Comment: You should have changed your Intent, not the name of second activity: ```Intent intent = new Intent( this, DisplayFloridactivity.class );```

Comment: Still no luck, the countdown display is still not showing. Not sure what's going on:   public void florida(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( this, DisplayFloridaactivity.class );
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editText );
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra( EXTRA_MESSAGE, message );
        startActivity( intent );
    }

    @SuppressLint("Registered")
    public class DisplayFloridaactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Comment: Do you actually call Florida method?